# How to add a layer in a functional tensorflow ResNet50 model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am building a image captioning model and for that I am using `ResNet50` as a feature extraction model. I have written the code, and it is working properly:

```
rs50 = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = (224, 224, 3))
new_input = rs50.input
hidden_layer = rs50.layers[-1].output

feature_extract = tf.keras.Model(new_input, hidden_layer)
```

Below are the last few lines of model summary (`feature_extract.summary()`):

```
 conv5_block3_3_bn (BatchNormal  (None, 7, 7, 2048)  8192        ['conv5_block3_3_conv[0][0]']    
 ization)                                                                                         
                                                                                                  
 conv5_block3_add (Add)         (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           ['conv5_block2_out[0][0]',       
                                                                  'conv5_block3_3_bn[0][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 conv5_block3_out (Activation)  (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           ['conv5_block3_add[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,587,712
Trainable params: 23,534,592
Non-trainable params: 53,120
```

But, the problem is that it is generating 2048 features. I don't have that much memory, so I wanted to change that `(None, 7, 7, 2048)` to `(None, 7, 7, 1024)`
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to find the last layer that has the output shape `(None, 14, 14, 1024)` and extract the model's layers until that point. The `conv4_block6_out` layer happens to be the last layer before the last block begins. This way, the last block is skipped altogether, which saves more memory. Then, apply one or more `Conv2D` or `MaxPooling` layers to get the shape `(None, 7, 7, 1024)`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
rs50 = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape = (224, 224, 3))

index = 0
for i, l in enumerate(rs50.layers):
  if 'conv4_block6_out' in l.name:
    index = i

new_input = rs50.input
hidden_layer = rs50.layers[index].output
output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, kernel_size=8)(hidden_layer)

feature_extract = tf.keras.Model(new_input, output)
print(feature_extract.output)
```

```
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 7, 7, 1024), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='conv2d_4/BiasAdd:0', description="created by layer 'conv2d_4'")
```